# Why when reporting to backgroundworker progresschanged to the progressbar the percentages i'm getting exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The code in the progresschanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int eventIndex = 0;
            try
            {
                eventIndex = (int)e.UserState;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.UserState == null ? "null" : e.UserState.GetType().FullName);
                throw;
            }
            else if (eventIndex == 4) // percent complete
            {
                progressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[4]);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid event index: " + eventIndex);
            }
        }
```

Then in the upload event of youtube i have this code:

```
string failed = "";
        double mbSent = 0;
        int percentComplete = 0;
        VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress vp = new VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress();
        private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {
            stringProgressReport[1] = "Uploading";
            ulong? ul = vp.TimeLeftMs;
            stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
            if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
            {
                fileuploadpercentages = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
                stringProgressReport[4] = fileuploadpercentages.ToString();
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, 4);
                stopwatch.Start();
                uploadstatus = "uploading file";
            }
```

The first thing is that i see using breakpoint that in the backgroundworker progresschanged event the value the progressbar get is 0.
The second problem is that i'm getting exception on the line:

```
progressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(stringProgressReport[4]);
```

Input string was not in a correct format

Now i see that the variable fileuploadpercentages is on 8 but i'm getting this exception.

When using a breakpoint i see in the variable stringProgressReport:

```
[0]   null
[1]   "Uploading"
[2]   "0"
[3]   "0"
[4]   "null"
```

First why i'm getting the exception if index 4 is "0" ?
Second why the reporting is 0 all the time ?

Comment: The element at index 4 is not "0" but "null". Indexes also start at 0. Your actual problem though is using an array for data that is not an array and using a string variable to store a number.

Comment: Why don't you use the proper parameter to pass the percent of work done? The first parameter of the call ReportProgress should be this value

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a plain `catch` (or even a `catch (Exception ex)`) - it's a bad practice. You should only ever catch exceptions that you can't program around.

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is not possible to explain each detail you are asking about. But certainly some useful things can be said:

> First why i'm getting the exception if index 4 is "0" ?

As you can see in the debugger display of `stringProgressReport`, the value at index `4` is `"null"`, not `"0"`. Trying to parse the string `"null"` as an `Int32` value will throw the exception you are seeing.

The code you posted clearly does assign your percentage calculation to element `4` here:

```
stringProgressReport[4] = fileuploadpercentages.ToString();
```

But it is just as obvious the debugger information (which no one here can confirm or refute, lacking a complete code example) indicates that something else has put the value of `"null"` in that element position.

Unless and until you will share a code example that is consistent with the stated observation, it's not possible to say for sure what is happening.

Note that having thrown an exception, the code will never get far enough to set the `ProgressBar.Value` property. So it's not much of a surprise it might remain at the value `0`.

> Second why the reporting is 0 all the time ?

I'm not sure what this question means. It's not reporting `0`. It's reporting `"null"`.

Since the code you posted doesn't match the array you posted, I guess it's possible there are other parts of that code that also don't match what you're actually debugging. For example, had you written the `fileuploadpercentages` computation differently — e.g. by omitting the cast to `double` before the first division in the expression — then that would explain a computed value of `0`.

But again, without a good code example, it's not possible to explain what you say is happening.

I do agree with other comments regarding your code, such as the very strange and very wrong way to pass state from your worker code to the progress event handler and your ignoring the `percentProgress` parameter of the `ReportProgress()` method.

I also agree that in general you should not use a blanket `catch`, but in this case you rethrow the exception so you're not really handling it, so much as simply observing it. The latter is much less of a problem (and in many cases, the right thing to do, though showing a message box in the middle of unwinding the stack is not necessarily the *best* idea in the world :) ).